# Создать и сразу обновить значение в одной процедуре PostgreSQL

Tags: база-данных, postgresql, plpgsql

Есть процедура для создания item в таблице. Нужно сразу после выполнения 'Create' обновить свойство 'pNameParentHierarhy' не покидайя процедру. Проблема в том что свойство 'pNameParentHierarhy' я задаю значением с другой процедуры, но мне нужен `id`. Т.е. сначала создать Item и потом уже с имеющимся id обновить свойство 'pNameParentHierarhy'

Вот процедура

```html
returns bigint
language sql
as $$

  insert into orgunits (
    orgunit_uid,
    parent_id,
    code,
    name,
    nameshort,
    nameparenthierarhy
    )
  values (
    pUid,
    pParentId,
    pCode,
    pName,
    pNameShort,
    pNameParentHierarhy = (SELECT * from portal.Portal_OrgUnitEmployeeTree_GeneratePathUrl(Id,true))
  )
  returning id;
$$;
```

Думал что такой вариант пропустит, но `id` еще нету

Как сразу после `create` вызвать операцию `update` и при этом вернуть `id` ?

Comment: `WITH cte AS (запрос на вставку с returning id) SELECT cte.id`

Comment: Не понял, данный код в каком порядке вызвать?

Comment: А поле id у вас serial, или какой то другой способ генерации используется ?

Comment: Да, id - serial

Comment: А функция Portal_OrgUnitEmployeeTree_GeneratePathUrl обращается к самой таблице  orgunits по переданному id, т.е. на момент ее вызова запись уже должна существовать ?

Comment: @Mike да, в этом и проблема, нужно сначала create и потом update. Впринципе с хранимки Portal_OrgUnitEmployeeTree_GeneratePathUrl  я могу вернуть id что б для общей записи сохранить(но это при условии если я создал уже запись) return id, вы можете показть как тут вторую операцию в одной харнимке провести?

Comment: В ответе все написал. тут только plpgsql, одним запросом не выходит, даже если insert в cte, как предложил @Akina, то update в пределах того же cte запись не видит и не меняет

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
returns bigint
language plpgsql
as $$
DECLARE
    new_id int;
BEGIN
  insert into orgunits (
    orgunit_uid,
    parent_id,
    code,
    name,
    nameshort
    )
  values (
    pUid,
    pParentId,
    pCode,
    pName,
    pNameShort
  )
  returning id into new_id;

  update orgunits set nameparenthierarhy = (SELECT * from portal.Portal_OrgUnitEmployeeTree_GeneratePathUrl(Id,true))
    where id = new_id;

  return new_id;
END
$$;
```

Comment: покамись не получается...читал ваше сообщение выше, надеялся что получится. Сейчас пробую через `nextval('orgunits_id_seq'::regclass)`, пробую передать следующий id. Сама процедура отрабатывается и создает новый item но в свойство все равно попадет null. Я так понимаю нужно все равно закончиться операцию create. Меня просто заверили что внутри транзации в процедуре `GeneratePathUrl` уже должно быть видно что "типа строка уже создана"..но нет...не получается.

Comment: @FX_Sektor Ну в моем варианте строка точно создана и все работает, проверено. В пределах одного запроса запись еще не видно, то же проверено. И да, я то же изначально думал брать id самому через nextval, но не судьба

Comment: Я наверно что-то не так делал с вашего примера. Все получилось! Большое Спасибо!